# Catching asyncio CancelledError

Tags: python-asyncio

Can someone explain this behaviour (python 3.11):

```
import asyncio as aio


async def cancel_me():
    while True:
        try:
            await aio.sleep(1)  # 1. sleep
        except aio.CancelledError:
            print(f"Cancelled {aio.current_task().get_name()}")
            try:
                await aio.sleep(1)  # 2. sleep
            except aio.CancelledError:
                print("Second sleep cancelled")
            await aio.sleep(1)  # 3. sleep
            print("Third sleep NOT cancelled")
            raise


async def main():
    tsk = aio.Task(cancel_me())
    await aio.sleep(0.1)
    tsk.cancel()

aio.run(main())
```

Running it gives:

```
Cancelled Task-2
Second sleep cancelled
Third sleep NOT cancelled
```

Why is the second sleep (from the top) cancelled while the third one runs to completion?

I was expecting either that both would be cancelled or none,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**updated**

The behavior does seem to be an arbitrariness resulting from an implementation detail. The second, but not third sleep is cancelled, even if it is moved out of the `except` block. If a second sleep is called in `main` prior to that, however, the second sleep in `cancel_me` runs fine.

This is the snippet I've been playing around, commenting parts and changing counters between executions to check the various outcomes:

```
async def cancel_me():
    for i in range(10):
        try:
            await aio.sleep(1)
        except aio.CancelledError:
            print(f"sleep canceled at counter = {i}")
        else:
            print(f"Ok at {i}")


async def main():
    tsk = aio.Task(cancel_me())
    for i in range(1):
        await aio.sleep(0.1)
        print(f"sending cancellation {i}")
        tsk.cancel()
        #if i == 0:
            #await aio.sleep(4)

aio.run(main())
```

Comment: To rephrase the question: What cancels the second sleep in my example? I now see the original question numbers the sleeps wrong.

Comment: sorry - you modified the code substantially., and I'd have to re-investigate to findout what is taking place. Not sure if I will have time for that.

Comment: yeah - ok, so it looks like my first guess was simply incorrect. I did some tests, and it is indeed unxpected and unexplained behavior - I'd say it is result of an implementation detail, or even a bug in cpython.  Do not write any code relying on this behavior, and figure out how to workaround it, if needed, is the way to go.

Comment: Thank you for confirming this behaviour. I was afraid was missing some aspect of asyncio cancelling.

Answer (score 0):

The workaround I ended up with was:

```
import asyncio as aio


async def cancel_me():
    while True:
        try:
            await aio.sleep(0.1)  # 1. sleep (do regular Task stuff)
        except aio.CancelledError:
            # Async cleanup
            print(f"Cancelled {aio.current_task().get_name()}")
            try:
                await aio.sleep(0.1)  # 2. sleep (ignore strange behaviour)
            except aio.CancelledError:
                pass
            await aio.sleep(1)  # 3. sleep (async cleanup)
            return


async def main():
    tsk = aio.Task(cancel_me())
    await aio.sleep(0.1)
    tsk.cancel()

aio.run(main())
```

This ensures that the strange behaviour is ignored at the cost of a 0.1 second delay, before commencing async cleanup. This is future proof in that once this quirk is fixed the code still runs.